# Display Data by month(Issue Month) on existing year as well past year stock data

Tags: mysql

I am working on a warehouse project. In this project I need to get output a report where it will summarize month wise issued(Sold) items. The output is per expecting from below MySQL query.

```
SELECT Product,Stock,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Issue_Date) = 1 THEN `Issue_Qty` END) jan, SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Issue_Date) = 2 THEN `Issue_Qty` END) feb, SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Issue_Date) = 3 THEN `Issue_Qty` END) mar, -------------- SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Issue_Date) = 12 THEN `Issue_Qty` END) December FROM product WHERE YEAR(Issue_Date) = 2021 GROUP by Product ORDER BY Product ASC
```

[image]

But issue is I am not able to get output data those items are not  issued on 2021. And if I remove ***where clause*** then all previous years sold items data are displaying in this report by respective month wise.

I want to get my report like below screen shot wise, where last two rows items not issued in 2021 but these items stock quantity will only display in report. Looking help from MySQL Guru to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for your help on this regard.

[image]

Comment: do you need product wise summing up stock along month value of specific year.

Comment: I think that should be done by filtering the data after retrieving them.

Answer (score 0):

As all product info is needed but balance will calculated by specific year and month so move WHERE clause info in every case statement along with year.
Stock value is summed up other wise it must be place on GROUP BY clause.

```
-- MySQL        
SELECT Product,SUM(Stock) Stock
         , SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Issue_Date) = 2021 AND MONTH(Issue_Date) = 1 THEN `Issue_Qty` END) jan
         , SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Issue_Date) = 2021 AND MONTH(Issue_Date) = 2 THEN `Issue_Qty` END) feb
         , SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Issue_Date) = 2021 AND MONTH(Issue_Date) = 3 THEN `Issue_Qty` END) mar
         -------------- 
         , SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Issue_Date) = 2021 AND MONTH(Issue_Date) = 12 THEN `Issue_Qty` END) December 
    FROM product 
    GROUP by Product 
    ORDER BY Product
```

Two ways for selecting year and month

1. YEAR(tdate) = '2021' AND MONTH(tdate) = 1
2. DATE_FORMAT(tdate, "%Y-%m") = '2021-01'

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e9e3e8ede5de378e2f4ed8df2b9fbe76